# Proof that, if factor groups are equal, then the subgroups are equal

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I'm reading a proof of the Correspondence Theorem and I'm seeing a step for which I'm not sure of the justification.  So suppose that $G$ is a subgroup and $K< H_{1},H_{2} <G$, and $K\trianglelefteq G$.  The move the proof makes is to say, "Since $H_{1}/K = H_{2}/K$ then $H_{1}=H_{2}$."

I've tried proving this by the following,

> Suppose $h_{1}\in H_{1}$ so that $h_{1}K \in H_{1}/K = H_{2}/K$ and so there is some $h_{2}$ such that $h_{1}K = h_{2}K$.  Since $h_{1}\in h_{1}K$ this implies there is some $k$ such that $h_{1}=h_{2}k$ ...

And at this point I don't see a way forward.

I think the big problem for me is that I don't have a criteria for "being in $H_{2}$".

Comment: $H$ is precisely the union of the cosets contained in $H/K$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it based on whacka's comment.  If I were going to keep with my very flat-footed proof style, then I would remark that $K<H_{2}$ and therefore $h_{1}=h_{2}k\in H_{2}$.

But the proof suggested by whacka is shorter and easier:  $H_{1}$ is the union of all cosets of $H_{1}/K$ is the union of all cosets of $H_{2}/K$ is $H_{2}$.